# How this question would be duplicate

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, reopen-closed

I recently asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19110061/equivalent-for-getobjectcontext-in-visual-studio-2012-vb-net) and the community marked it as duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16320098/how-to-get-objectcontext-to-compile) one,How my question is duplicate of it?

My question seeks the following :

- searching an equivalent for getobjectcontext() in vb.net

But the question which was marked as duplicate was related to compilation of getobjectcontext() , how these questions were duplicate?

Comment: I voted to re-open..

Comment: same here. definitely not a duplicate

Comment: Community makes mistakes, too :)

Comment: [meta-tag:status-completed] :)

Comment: thanks for the support my question got reopened :)

Comment: @Mołot not sure it's a mistake, I pinged the first who voted (300K+ user) maybe he'll explain.

Comment: This type of question might belong in the Stack Overflow Meta.